# Processmaker wrong PHP version

Tags: processmaker

Process maker github readme (4.8.1) says it needs PHP 8.1
https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker

I am trying to run it but when it compiles on PHP 8.1 I get an error saying that constants are not supported in traits.

I can see in this file
https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/blob/develop/ProcessMaker/Traits/ProjectAssetTrait.php
That there is a constant in at least one trait. This is stopping it compiling in php 8.1.

Constants in traits are a new feature added in PHP 8.2 (https://php.watch/versions/8.2/constants-in-traits)

So I know that this requirement is wrong in the readme file.

- I tried to submit a PR to fix this but they do not accept PR's. I also can't seem to raise an issue on the repo.

I want to know what version of PHP will work. I am having other problems compiling in PHP 8.2 so I am not sure if this is correct or not.

Does anyone know the correct PHP version to run processmaker 4.8.1?

More importantly. When I found out, how can I submit a change to the docs to help other opensource developers who may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have got my processmaker setup working and I can confirm it required PHP 8.2
Hopefully the docs will catch up